# Display Camera created in C++ on VideoOutput in QML

Tags: c++, qt, camera, qml

I have problem displaying the **QCamera** created in C++ to **VideoOutput** that is in QML.
If i use this way where camera is in QML, everything is fine i get the video output:

```
Item{
        VideoOutput
        {
            id: videoOutput
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: camera
        }
        Camera
        {
            id: camera
        }
}
```

But in my case camera is not in QML. I am creating it in C++.  I have tried to create it in C++ and set it as contextProperty and therefore use it in source in VideoOutput in qml. So this is my main.cpp.

```
QCamera* camera;

    QList<QCameraInfo> cameras = QCameraInfo::availableCameras();
    foreach (const QCameraInfo &cameraInfo, cameras)
    {
        qDebug() << cameraInfo.description();

        camera = new QCamera(cameraInfo);
    }

    if(camera)
    {
        qDebug() << "setContextProperty  camera ";
        engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("mCamera", camera);
    }
```

And everything is fine camera is detected and i am using it in QML like this:

```
Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    Item
    {
        id: cameraView
        height: 230
        width: 300
        anchors.centerIn: parent

        VideoOutput
        {
            id: videoOutput
            anchors.fill: parent
            source: mCamera
        }
    }
```

But there is no video output in this way. Is this possible to achive? Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you do that as described in the [documentation](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-videooutput.html#source-prop)?: _If you are extending your own C++ classes to interoperate with VideoOutput, you can either provide a QObject based class with a mediaObject property that exposes a QMediaObject derived class that has a QVideoRendererControl available, or you can provide a QObject based class with a writable videoSurface property that can accept a QAbstractVideoSurface based class and can follow the correct protocol to deliver QVideoFrames to it._

Comment: i will check that and try it. Thank you so much @folibis

Comment: The linked doc is for when you want to display something other than a regular camera

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just in case someone is still interested in.
You can use the Camera->setViewfinder() function.

I have a wrapper class for the QCamera the do some other stuff.
Among others, there is a public slot to set the cameras viewfinder from QML.

```
void MyCamClass::setViewFinder(QObject *vf)
{
  if(Camera)
    Camera->setViewfinder(qobject_cast<QAbstractVideoSurface *>(vf));
}
```

On QML side, you will have a

```
VideoOutput {
  id: vOutput
}
```

If you want to activate your camera, you can call:

```
mCamera->setviewFinder(vOutput.videoSurface);
```

mCamera is a object of MyCamClass class and registered to QML environment.
Make sure to start your camera before set the viewfinder.

Answer (score 1):

You can't directly assign a `QCamera` to the source of a `VideoOutput`.

What you can do is set the [`deviceId`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtmultimedia-camera.html#deviceId-prop) of the QML `Camera` to match the one from your `QCamera`:

In your C++ :

```
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("deviceId", cameraInfo.deviceName);
```

and in your QML :

```
Camera {
    id: camera
    deviceId: cameraDeviceId
}

VideoOutput {
    id: videoOutput
    anchors.fill: parent
    source: camera
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer @GrecKo. But with this approach i will just pass device id to QML and there camera will be set without getting the settings from C++. Am i Right? Lets say i modify my C++ QCamera and i want that modified camera to be used in QML. Will i create just new QML camera type with this approach?
Thanks in advance.